# Apache IP address working but localhost does not

Tags: linux, apache

I downloaded Apache2 and it is currently running. I typed in my IP address and it brings me to the "It Works!" page, however when I type in localhost or 127.0.0.1 I receive an error. Can someone tell me whats up?

Comment: What error? Look into Apache log files (perhaps `/var/log/webaccess.log` etc)

Answer (score 1):

check 127.0.0.1 able to ping or not with same machine. 
check /etc/hosts file having 127.0.0.1 entry or not?
check in apache configuration file Listen 0.0.0.0:80 or not?